# How to do jQuery's .trigger() in Vue

Tags: vue.js

What is the the best way in `Vue` to replace `jQuery's` short and sweet `.trigger()` for an external element outside of the Vue app.

Example:

```js
$('body').trigger('to-trigger');
```

I was able to put `$('body').trigger('to-trigger');` inside my Vue app and it works :/ Just not sure this is the correct thing to do.

Comment: `this.method()`

Comment: If you use jQuery to trigger something on an element outside of Vue, this is the correct solution.